# JAVA Classpath and jersey client

Tags: jersey, jersey-client, javax.ws.rs

I had this problem for last few weeks and whenever i run a java application the following exception :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/core/util/FeaturesAndProperties

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.sun.jersey.core.util.FeaturesAndProperties
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was

```
jerseyclient.jar, jersey.jar and javax.ws.rs.jar
```

was there in JDK classpath and also there a dependency shich had these files so the that caused this exception. Hope it helps someone !!!